# Parsing 1track ...information about point

Tags: python, selenium, parsing, beautifulsoup

I use selenium and beautiful soap. Wait 30 seconds until the pop-up window loads, closes it, and then reads the information again. But the information about the points where the parcel was, as if hidden. I was advised to try the usser agent, but he did not help either.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
import time
import re
import requests

driver = 

webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\Yres\\Downloads\\
chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe")

driver.get('https://1track.ru/tracking/RU341961010HK')

time.sleep(30)

driver.find_element_by_class_name ("close").click()

driver.get('https://1track.ru/tracking/RU341961010HK')

source = driver.page_source
driver.quit() 

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "html.parser")
print(soup)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all that data in a nice json format using `.post`

```
import requests
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

url = 'https://1track.ru/ajax/tracking2'

headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36'}
payload = {'tracks[0][track]': 'RU341961010HK'}

data = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload).json()

jsonObj = data['JSON']

# you can do whatever you'd like here. But I just threw it into a dataframe
df = json_normalize(jsonObj['data']['events']['data'])
```

**Output:**

a dataframe with the following columns:

```
['attribute', 'attribute.name', 'attribute.name_orig', 'courier.country',
   'courier.country_code', 'courier.image', 'courier.name',
   'courier.track', 'courier.uri', 'date', 'date_format.F',
   'date_format.H', 'date_format.M', 'date_format.Y', 'date_format.d',
   'date_format.i', 'date_format.m', 'date_format.s', 'days', 'daysclass',
   'details', 'details.name', 'details.name_orig', 'kk', 'payment',
   'place', 'place.name', 'place.name_orig', 'placeto', 'status', 'time',
   'value', 'weight', 'zip', 'zip.code', 'zip.country.code',
   'zip.country.name', 'zip.fullcode', 'zip.location.address',
   'zip.location.lat', 'zip.location.long', 'zip.name', 'zip.type']
```

and the dataframe (to just show first full 3 rows:

```
print(df.head(3).to_string())
  attribute                           attribute.name                      attribute.name_orig courier.country courier.country_code     courier.image  courier.name  courier.track   courier.uri        date date_format.F date_format.H date_format.M date_format.Y date_format.d date_format.i date_format.m date_format.s    days daysclass details                 details.name            details.name_orig  kk payment  place      place.name place.name_orig  placeto   status      time value  weight  zip zip.code zip.country.code zip.country.name zip.fullcode  zip.location.address  zip.location.lat  zip.location.long        zip.name zip.type
0       NaN                  Передача в авиакомпании                     Hand over to airline           Китай                   CN       cainiao.png       CAINIAO  RU341961010HK       cainiao  29.01.2019       January            14           Jan          2019            29            59            01            00  4 день   success   False                          NaN                          NaN   0    None  False             NaN             NaN    False  transit  14:59:00  None       0  NaN      NaN              NaN              NaN          NaN                   NaN               NaN                NaN             NaN      NaN
1       NaN  Airline departure from original country  Airline departure from original country           Китай                   CN       cainiao.png       CAINIAO  RU341961010HK       cainiao  29.01.2019       January            13           Jan          2019            29            34            01            00  4 день   success   False                          NaN                          NaN   1    None  False             NaN             NaN    False  transit  13:34:00  None       0  NaN      NaN              NaN              NaN          NaN                   NaN               NaN                NaN             NaN      NaN
2     False                                      NaN                                      NaN          Россия                   RU  russian-post.png  Почта России  RU341961010HK  russian-post  29.01.2019       January            10           Jan          2019            29            46            01            00  4 день   success     NaN  Экспорт международной почты  Экспорт международной почты   2    None    NaN  Гонконг HKHKGA  Гонконг HKHKGA    False  transit  10:46:00  None       0  NaN   HKHKGA               HK        Hong Kong    HK_HKHKGA                   NaN               0.0                0.0  Гонконг HKHKGA      int
```

The process gets the data:

```
data = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload).json()
```

[image]

And then I just store the JSON from it:

```
jsonObj = data['JSON']
```

[image]

Then I can "unpack" the data that I need, and store as a dataframe:

```
df = json_normalize(jsonObj['data']['events']['data'])
```

[image]

and here's the dataframe:

[image]

Comment: Wow! It really works !!! Thank you very much!. And then I will be able to handle with the help of BeautifulSoup? And where can I read about this technique with Json?and why he sees this information?

Comment: I am sorry, put your extra in the code. Variable "json_normalize"  undefined and I do not understand how to connect  dataframe with coloumns "Index"

Comment: oh sorry, forgot to import it. check edit. I'm not clear what you mean by "I do not understand how to connect dataframe with coloumns "Index" "

Comment: I mean, the Index([ ])  is not defined, where can I do this? pandas i have installed and variable "json_normalize" initialized normally

Comment: I'm still not quite getting what you mean. there is an index for the dataframe: `RangeIndex(start=0, stop=15, step=1)`.

Comment: sorry for my English((... "Output: a dataframe with coloumns:

    Index(['attribute', 'attribute.name', "]...........handler says "Index  not define"
and I still don't understand how you tied him up with "df"

Comment: Oh. I was just printing out the column names of the dataframe so you could see them. I'll go back and add some comments in the solution.

Comment: I use Spyder to do that. It's nice way to debug too as you can get views of your variables as you're working through the code

Comment: hello again!)).. tell me how can I import my libraries installed using pip into spider?

Comment: I have spyder installed through the Anaconda distribution. My suggestion would be to do that.

Comment: that is, should I install them for go via the anaconda console?

Comment: yes. if you do it through the anaconda terminal, it should then install the package in your anaconda environment. You can search for libraries [here](https://anaconda.org/). Usually you'll see something like: conda install. But pip install should still work though in your anaconda terminal

Comment: Hello again! I wanted to ask, how did you understand that the URL should be exactly with "ajax / tracking2"? and why payload = {'tracks [0] [track]': '' + trek + ''}? is it just a definition of a two-dimensional array for a track?